# ACC API - pushpin support / assigned user

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

I've been using the BIM 360 API last year to develop an application based on the online solution ACC, which was compatible with all the methods back then. Now with the new migration to the Autodesk Construction Cloud API, many functionalities were deprecated and removed.

I've tried:

- fetching specific data for pushpin issues related to a 3D model in a project (ex: owner / assigned users)
- ADDING PUSHPIN ISSUES, the API doesn't allow it any more.
- modify same specific data on issues (ex: assigned users)

Is there a new request to call to get those data ? Will those removed functionalities come back in the next weeks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there still are gasp between BIM 360 and ACC Issues API.

Creating "pushpin" is not possible using ACC API.

SCCOM-13366: "Issue API: support Pushpin Issue (issue with markup)"

For assigning users, GET project users (a part of admin API) is still missing.
For this, there is a workaround to use Data Connector API, although it is not ideal.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/issues/retrieve-available-members-roles-companies/

Comment: thank you for your response. Do you know if there is any date for an update release, or a major update of the API planned?

Comment: Sorry, we don't know yet for both topics.  (I'm hoping to have get project user sooner. But I cannot promise anything.)